# Bokeh GeoMaps: plotting labels over regions/countries

Tags: python, maps, bokeh, geography

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am plotting a map of United Kingdom at the regional level using Bokeh, with regions filled with different colors graded on a target variable (from green to red depending on the level).

I would like to plot the name of the region (stored in a variable called nuts1_label) in the map, however I am not able to do it.
I was able to create an hover, that however is visible only in the interactive version while I need the names of the regions to be permanently shown.

I plot here the code:

---

```
g_var = 'target_var' 

#Define color palette.
palette = col_map

#Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors.
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = merged[g_var].min(), high = merged[g_var].max(), nan_color = '#d9d9d9')

#Create color bar. 
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=10,width = 500, height = 20,
border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal')

#Create figure object.

p = figure(title = 'Title', 
       plot_height = 700 , plot_width = 500, toolbar_location = None, tools = [hover])
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.visible = False
p.title.text_font_size = '8pt'

#Add patch renderer to figure. 
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource, fill_color = {'field' : g_var, 'transform' : color_mapper},
      line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)

#Specify figure layout and hover
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')

hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [ ('Region','@nuts1_label')])


#Display figure inline in Jupyter Notebook.
output_notebook()
export_png(p, filename="F1.png")
show(p)
```

Thanks again for your help.
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

You need either the [Label/LabelSet annotations](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#labels) or the text glyph (a [good example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#hex-tiles)).